# HTTP 500 Error on php document IIS 8 and PHP 7.0.2

Tags: php, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I'm trying to migrate my LAMP application to Windows/IIS.
I have a Windows 2012 R2 server.
I'm following the instructions at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994592.aspx (modified slightly: I used add-windowsfeature Web-Server -includeAllSubFeature to install IIS +CGI).
I have the vc++ 2015 redist installed (both x86 and x64).
PHP 7.0.2 is installed at d:\php.
IIS Module Handler for php is configured:

```
name            : PHP_via_FastCGI
path            : *.php
verb            : *
modules         : FastCgiModule
scriptProcessor : D:\php\php-cgi.exe
resourceType    : Either
requireAccess   : Script
```

d:\php is in the PATH environment variable.
My php.ini settings are the php.ini-development settings with these changes:

- extension_dir = "ext"
- cgi.force_redirect = 0
- fastcgi.impersonate = 1
- fastcgi.logging = 0
- extension=php_ curl.dll
- log_errors = On
- error_log = syslog

The above configuration works on a Windows 7 desktop and on a 2012 R2 server NOT joined to the corporate domain, but on two 2012 R2 servers in the domain I get a 500 Internal Server error when trying to launch http://localhost/test.php.

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php contains:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I'm not seeing any error information in the Windows Event log.

Running "php c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php" in the cmd window gives me the expected phpinfo.

I have checked the NTFS permissions on the d:\php folder and the c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder. They are too many to list, but SYSTEM has full control on both folders and the WWWPublishing service is running as Local System.

Any ideas of what to look for to find out why this isn't working?

Comment: Would you care to show us the code that's throwing an error?

Comment: This is probably due to an error in your code, so please include it in your answer

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?> is my current code. The application I am porting is a third party application and pretty large. It currently works fine on a LAMP server.

Comment: Did you check IIS logs?

Comment: I just have default logging. It shows the access attempts and 500 status. e.g.: #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-01-28 23:04:56 127.0.0.1 GET /test.php - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 500 0 1413 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out the IIS_IUSRS group needed full-control NTFS access to the d:\php folder.